# How to pass file name as column in Spark

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

I need to pass array of Hadoop file path to spark.read

```
status= Array(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus)
```

I tried:

```
val s = spark.read.format("json").load(status: _*)
```

Error:

```
<console>:32: error: overloaded method value load with alternatives:

  (paths: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>

  (path: String)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

cannot be applied to (org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus)

       val s = spark.read.format("json").load(status: _*)
```

How to pass file name as column in Spark?

Comment: The error means that you need to pass the paths as Strings instead of FileStatus objects.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get file paths from the array of [`FileStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) objects first.

This should work fine:

```
val files = status.map(_.getPath().toString)

val df = spark.read.format("json").load(files: _*)
```

Comment: Can we create an extra column containing the filename?

Comment: Use [`input_file_name`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#input_file_name) : `df.withColumn("filename", input_file_name())`

Comment: Yes thank you for your response. 
I have already implemented these changes.